# How to deal with dependencies when deploying a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm setting up a `gulp` build file for a `node.js` project and I really don't have any experience with either of them.

So basically what I'm doing is simply copying all the code to a deployment directory, but I'm unsure of how to handle all the dependencies that are stored in `node_modules`. Do you simply copy all of them as well, or is there a more preferred way of doing it?

```
gulp.task('deliver', function() {
  gulp.src('src/*.html').pipe(gulp.dest('deployment/'));
  gulp.src('src/*.js').pipe(gulp.dest('deployment/'));
  gulp.src('src/games/').pipe(gulp.dest('deployment/'));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to package & deploy Node.js + express web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259181/how-to-package-deploy-node-js-express-web-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way would be to have a package.json file that lists all your dependencies. Then as part of your deployment process run `npm install` which will go through your package.json and install any necessary packages in the node_modules folder.

Comment: Ah, so I've pretty much completely misunderstood then. Thanks!