# How to "upload" my nodejs source code to production server?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, deployment, production-environment

I am not asking about deploying Node.js app or how do I deal with node_modules package, I am talking about "upload" my own nodejs code to production server.

So far I have tried 3 ways, each with its own pros & cons

**git clone**. To reduce to the cloned stuff I use `git clone --depth 1 -b release_branch`. But still I got the files I do not need for deployment, e.g except for `.git` I also get documents (b/c I put documents in my git repo).

**npm install**. use `npm install git+https://gitusername:gitpassword@myserver/path/to/repo.git`. With proper `package.json files` setting I can get my source codes only, which is what I want. But the problem is the directory structure. After running npm install, the directory is like this,

```
.
├── node_modules
└── package-lock.json

My package is located inside node_modules alongside with its own dependencies.
```

**npm pack**. Then upload (scp in my case) the tgz file to server, then `npm install tgz_file.tgz --production`  But it has the same problem with npm install git+https. It is probably better than `npm install git+https` b/c I can control my releases.

So is there other ways (simple) that I can get proper directory structure and source codes only ?

BTW, I know this [nodejs express app deploying to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651764/nodejs-express-app-deploying-to-production) but their discussion is not the same as mine.

----- update -----

Now I am kinda sure `npm install tarball` has some bug, so I just `tar xf & npm i` I believe this is the simplest solution.

Comment: what is the difference between uploading code for deployment and your scenario?

Comment: no difference. first upload my code then npm install then npm start

Comment: have you tried scp ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what is your problem, but I think with scp (and may a small shell script) you will have control over the trasfered files.